# How can I get date in this format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

Apparently I should get ISO8601 UTC format and in order to get this, I am using moment.js

```
let time1 = moment().format()
let time2 = moment().add('year', 1).format()
```

The `console.log()` outputs:

```
2018-04-23T15:52:47+02:00
2019-04-23T15:52:47+02:00
```

But I should get something like:

```
2015-07-13T22%3A00%3A00Z
```

How can I achieve this please? Isn't this ISO8601 UTC?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for moment.js? The formatting/time zone options are in there.

Comment: Yes I have.. but couldn't find it. 
Could you help please and I will vote.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 1):

The format you're looking to achieve is already ISO8601, the difference is that it's been url-encoded ready to be sent via the querystring.

To get this format, use `encodeURIComponent()`, like this:

```js
var input = '2015-07-13T22:00:00Z';
var output = encodeURIComponent(input);

console.log(output);
```